# Not able to Access the Mobile camera and Microphone using mobile browser in PWA(react js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, progressive-web-apps, getusermedia

I am trying to access the camera and microphone through mobiles browser.
It is not giving any pop up asking for permissions for accessing the same. But we are able to access the same on localhost using `the laptop's browser`.

I am using `react js` for this .

What I tried is ,

```
startCamera = () => {
    if (!('mediaDevices' in navigator)) {
      navigator.mediaDevices = {};
    }

    if (!('getUserMedia' in navigator.mediaDevices)) {
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia = function (constraints) {
        var getUserMedia = navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

        if (!getUserMedia) {
          return Promise.reject(new Error('getUserMedia is not implemented!'));
        }

        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
          getUserMedia.call(navigator, constraints, resolve, reject);
        });
      }
    }
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      video: { facingMode: 'user' },
      audio: true
    }).then((stream) => {
      console.log('recording started');
      return this.startRecording(stream)
    }).then(recordedChunks => {
      let recordedBlob = new Blob(recordedChunks, { type: "video/webm" });

      this.props.getVideoUploadLink(this.props.candidateScore[0].jdId, this.props.candidateScore[0].resumeId, recordedBlob);

      this.setState({ downloadUrl: URL.createObjectURL(recordedBlob) });
    })
      .catch(console.log);
  }
```

So, is there anything extra I need to incorporate to access the permision through mobile browser? .Thanks.

Comment: If it's working on localhost and not on another IP, it's probably because you're not serving the site over HTTPS.

Comment: yes . what we do is that we actually use the ifconfig and take that Ip and try to use that in the mobile browser

Answer (score 2):

From Chrome 48 forward, calls to getUserMedia are ignored if the protocol isn't HTTPS. Except for localhost, which still accepts insecure HTTP for development purposes.

If you are trying to access from to your mobile to your laptop, you'll need HTTPS.

Some boilerplates like Create React App allow you t start the development server with HTTPS:

> HTTPS=true npm start

Comment: So, I trieed with this but this is not working. what I do is that I actually take the ip address of my machine and then hit it in mobile browser

Comment: yes I tried that as well.. but it says site can not be reached

Comment: If you could access it before but not with https, you probably failed to initiate the server with https.